# How can we configure the Jquery Countdown Plugin for using AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, php

We would like to make a countdown using Jquery Countdown plugin. It should be connected with PHP through AJAX. basically we need this countdown for our portal ( if there is a URL more than 12 hrs old than that url will automatically remove from Mysql.)

We have designed a code for this but, its not working properly using AJAX call. it's working fine expect ajax call.

Please look at the codes.

**HTML / Javascript**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery Countdown</title>
<link href="jquery.countdown.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
#defaultCountdown { width: 240px; height: 45px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js">          </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function serverTime(){ 
var time = null; 
$.ajax({url: 'http://localhost/portal/audit/test3.php', 
    async: false, dataType: 'text', 
    success: function(text) { 
        time = new Date(text); 
    }, error: function(http, message, exc) { 
        time = new Date(); 
}}); 
return time; 
}
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ 
until:liftoffTime, serverSync: serverTime}); 
   </script>
   </head>
    <body>
    <div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1 
header("Expires: Fri, 1 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past 
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"); // MIME type 
$now = new DateTime(); 
echo $now->format("M j, Y H:i:s O")."\n"; 
?>
```

Please suggest me for this countdown plugin. we used this plugin from this url :- http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#serverSync

**Updated**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function liftOff() { 
    var time = null; 
    $.ajax({url: 'http://localhost/portal/audit/test3.php', 
        async: false, dataType: 'text', 
        success: function(text) { 
            time = new Date(text); 
        }, error: function(http, message, exc) { 
            time = new Date(); 
    }}); 
    return time; 
}
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ 
    until:liftoffTime, onExpiry: liftOff}); 



</script>
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the JavaScript console?

Comment: There is no error means no display ....

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the page, you need to use the call back "onExpiry"

```
$(selector).countdown({ 
    until: liftoffTime, onExpiry: liftOff}); 

function liftOff() { 
    // run ajax here
}
```

Comment: You already have that bit, you just need to put your ajax in the liftoff function above.

Comment: Please look at the Updated Codes in the Question. Is this Ok? If yes, then it's not working.